# Azure blob see image file in browser

Tags: php, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I have stored image file in my azure container. I want to see that image without downloading it in local.

I am getting this array after applying function,

```
print_r($storageClient->listBlobs('container_name'));
```

**Array**

```
Array
(
[0] => Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_BlobInstance Object
    (
        [_data:protected] => Array
            (
                [container] => container_name
                [name] => 1_1.jpg
                [snapshotid] => 
                [etag] => 0x8D195A526225
                [lastmodified] => Wed, 03 Sep 2014 15:44:51 GMT
                [url] => http://mtes.blob.core.windows.net/container_name/1_1.jpg
                [size] => 8235
                [contenttype] => application/octet-stream
                [contentencoding] => 
                [contentlanguage] => 
                [cachecontrol] => 
                [blobtype] => BlockBlob
                [leasestatus] => unlocked
                [isprefix] => 
                [metadata] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

how can I show image in browser?

Comment: Providing the blob container is allowing anonymous read, the 'url' parameter is what you're after. Please note however that "without doanloading" isn't really possible since even to view, the bits of the blob will need to be sent to the requestor for rendering. :)

Comment: Yes. Can we setup privileges on this? If user is logged in, then he can see the image and access direct url. If he is not logged in then no access! right now i set it up as public. `$storageClient->setContainerAcl($blob_container, Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob::ACL_PUBLIC_CONTAINER);`

Comment: The blob container does not understand application centric security state. So it would have no idea if the user was logged in or not. For what you are trying to do, you'll need to setup a façade service. This takes a request (URL w/ query parameters), and uses that to a) authenticate the request and b) find, retrieve, and subsequently delivery the content to the requestor. The easiest way to do this is simply re-routing the blob stream directly to the requestor after you've authorized them.

Comment: You can restrict access to the image by retrieving a SharedAccessSignature for the blob in question if the user is logged in.  This prevents direct access unless the signature is provided - in addition, the signature is time restricted so it cannot be reused...

Check out -> http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=901 for an example...